# Reload inline and src defined scripts during AJAX page transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, barbajs

I'm trying to implement [barba.js](https://barba.js.org/) on a `HubSpot` site.

Issue with `HubSpot` is that it renders our `js` related to `forms` or `js` related to custom `modules` within `<script><script>` tags.

As such, currently, with my `barba` implementation, if I transition over to a page with a `HubSpot` form for example, that form will not show and `js` related to my modules (such as `slick js`, they do not work either.

Using the hooks defined below (from the docs), I've added an `ajax` call to attempt to reload `scripts` that have a `src` defined. However, I cannot test if that is working because the `js` from my custom modules are not working.

| Property | Description |
| --- | --- |
| data.current | Current page related |
| data.next | Next page related |
| data.trigger | Link that triggered the transition |

Question being, is there a way for me to reload `scripts` without `src` defined?

Here is my current implementation:

```js
function delay(n){
  n = n || 2000;
  return new Promise((done) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      done();
    }, n);
  });
}

barba.init({
  sync: true,
  prefetchIgnore: true,
  debug: true,
  transitions: [{

    async leave(data){
      const done = this.async();
      await delay(200);
      done();
    },

    async beforeEnter({ next, container }) {
      $(container).find('script').each(function (i, script) {
        var $script = $(script);
        $.ajax({
          url: $script.attr('src'),
          cache: true,
          dataType: 'script',
          success: function () {
            $script.trigger('load');
          }
        });
      });
    },



    async enter(data){
      let scrollX = 0
      let scrollY = 0

      barba.hooks.leave(() => {
        scrollX = barba.history.current.scroll.x;
        scrollY = barba.history.current.scroll.y;
      });

      window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
    },

    async once(data){
      console.log("test");
    },

  }]
});
```

**Here is a working demo**

- [Page 1](http://5465287-hs-sites-com.sandbox.hs-sites.com/barba-page-1)
- [Page 2](http://5465287-hs-sites-com.sandbox.hs-sites.com/barba-page-2)

Follow these steps:

1. Click on `page 1`. Notice how the `HubSpot` form loads.
2. Click on `page 2`
3. Notice how the `slick slider` module isn't working
4. Now refresh `page 2` and you will see `slick` is working.
5. Navigate to `page 1` and you'll see the form is not working now.

Visual of issue:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/)? Use static template create two pages: main with barba and other mimicking Hubspot. Just a potsot, can you put content coming from HubSpot in `<iframe>`?

Comment: Also note, that when you go from `page 1` and onto `page 2`, then go back to `page 1`, everything on that page will work. This is because whatever page you initially land on the JS for that is rendered, but JS for pages navigated to (that `barba` has to `prefetch`) do not. See my steps to recreate in my question.

Comment: @onkarruikar - In addition to the above, this is why the fixed header works. `.fixed` is added via JS and this works when you go on a new page because that JS has been `fetched` from `barba` on whatever page is loaded.

Comment: @onkarruikar - Based on your demo, it doesn't look like your page is transitioning the same as mine (yours looks like it is loading in the new page as default, as in `barba` isn't transitioning). I have `barba debug mode` enabled, and in my `console` I can see the following: https://i.imgur.com/X9d2Q53.png - Do you see barba finding a transition on your end?

Comment: In my gif I've opened dev console see at ~33s. The log does say it found transition.

Comment: @onkarruikar - hm, this is weird, here is my demo with console open: https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-6c5aa50f6e.gif

Comment: @onkarruikar - In your demo, after page change, I cannot see the console log `[@barba/core]  Transition found [page] {leave: ƒ, beforeEnter: ƒ, enter: ƒ, once: ƒ, async: ƒ}`, which appears on mine. In your demo, it seems as `barba` is finding the initial transition, but not after page change?

Comment: yeah! for me the entire page is loading not just the content. I tried on other browsers same thing. Delete irrelevant comments we are triggering the limit. After looking carefully, it does find and log the transition before going to next page, but after a second it reloads entire page. Barba is not suppressing anchor tag default click behavior in my browser. I've disabled all plugins.

Comment: @onkarruikar - Is it behaving the same for you on a mobile device?